# how to detect change for a radio button list

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul id='theList'>
<li><input type='radio' name='foo' val='1' /></li>
<li><input type='radio' name='foo' val='2' /></li>
<li><input type='radio' name='foo' val='3' /></li>
<li><input type='radio' name='foo' val='4' /></li>
<li><input type='radio' name='foo' val='5' /></li>
</ul>
```

I want to show an alert('hi') when some radio input is selected. 
I tried this:

```
$(function(){
   $('#theList input[type="radio"]').live('change', function(){
      alert('hi');
   });
});
```

and it doesn't work.
(I use live because I change the content of the ul via ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'change' event handler is probably not being bound correctly.  live() doesn't always work when you are dynamically altering the elements you want to bind to.

just to test, try ajaxComplete()

something like :

```
$('#theList').ajaxComplete(function(){
   <!-- attach change event -->
});
```

Comment: Just a clarification for anyone reading this answer: `ajaxComplete` will work only when the inputs are added after an ajax call. It won't work if the items are added dinamically but not using ajax in the process of adding it.

Answer (score 1):

Use .die() so you don't stack multiple click events to the radios. Also, it's the "click" event you need, not "change".

```
$(function(){
   $('#theList input[type="radio"]').die().live('click', function(){
      alert('hi');
   });
});
```

Comment: According to the documentation, [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) does work with radio buttons. Also, can you clarify why you're using `die()` in an init function?

Comment: I mentioned it in my original answer, I put it there so that the elements don't stack the same event multiple times except just once. Change works, however I always use "click" for the radio buttons since it works across all browsers without issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use .trigger() in your ajax at the point where the checkbox gets selected.

I've coded up an example where clicking a link triggers the change:

**jQuery**

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    $('#theList input[val="2"]').click().trigger('contentchanged')
});

$('#theList input[type="radio"]').bind('contentchanged', function() {
  alert('hi');
});
```

Check it out in action on jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/HQs8g/

Hope this helps Alex

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the event to the parent element instead, this way it will catch the change event of any `input[type="radio"]` tag inside, no matter if the tag came from the server at first load or if it was added later to the DOM:

```
$(function(){
   $('#theList').on('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function(){
      console.log("hi: ", $(this).val())
   });
});
```

Also, notice that your inputs should have their `value` property set instead of `val`. For example:

```
<input type='radio' name='foo' value='1' />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this simple jquery event which triggered whenever user click on radio button.

```
 $(document).on('change', '#theList li input', function() {
     alert('hi');
   });
```

This event triggers whenever someone click on radio button

Comment: Please note that this won't work for elements added dynamically to the DOM. That was the issue the OP initially had.

Comment: please use $(document).on('change', '#theList li input', function() {});

Comment: I was just pointing that out. I had posted an answer before covering that matter, just saying in case you wanted to edit yours.

Comment: thank for mentioning this I have updated my answer :)